Activate Create Index and Drop Index for Automatic tuning in bicep for sql database
How can I activate the automatic tuning Create and Drop index using bicep?
I've search and there seems to be this resource in Bicep Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/automaticTuning but I don't have the options to activate only Create and Drop index.
Update 1:
There's my Bicep code:
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-02-01-preview' = {
  name: '${appName}-${environment}-sql'
  location: location
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: '${environment}-admin'
    administratorLoginPassword: sqlPassword
    minimalTlsVersion: '1.2'
    restrictOutboundNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    publicNetworkAccess: publicNetworkAccess ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-02-01-preview' existing = {
  name: sqlServerName
}

resource sqlServerDatabase 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-02-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlServer
  name: '${appName}-${environmentName}-db-${dbName}'
  location: location
  sku: environmentSettings[toLower(environmentName)].sku
}


Could you share the code here? @Antoine Brisebois-Roy

It is possible to set the automatic tuning create and drop indexes with the resource provider Microsoft.Sql/servers/advisors in bicep.
The functionality of this resource works only to reference the existing resource in the latest version releases. If you want to deploy a new resource, you need to use the older API version: 2014-04-01 as detailed below.
main.bicep:
param servername string = 'myserverj'
@minLength(1)
param servernameAdminLogin string = 'jahnaviadmin'
param servernameAdminLoginPassword string = 'xxxx'

resource server 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2023-08-01-preview' = {
  name: servername
  location: 'West Europe'
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: servernameAdminLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: servernameAdminLoginPassword
    version: '12.0'
  }
}

resource ForceLast 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/advisors@2014-04-01' = {
  parent: server
  name: 'ForceLastGoodPlan'
  properties: {
    autoExecuteValue: 'Enabled'
  }
}

resource Create 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/advisors@2014-04-01' = {
  parent: server
  name: 'CreateIndex'
  properties: {
    autoExecuteValue: 'Enabled'
  }
}

resource Drop 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/advisors@2014-04-01' = {
  parent: server
  name: 'DropIndex'
  properties: {
    autoExecuteValue: 'Enabled'
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:

You can also refer this SO to enable it using ARM template.

I find it weird that we need to use the 2014 api to activate functionalities on a 2023 resource API. What is the reason behind that?

It is because in updated versions, the resource deployment is not possible with the above advisor resource. Only the existing can refer. Default implementation is like that. @AntoineBrisebois-Roy
